# CardLayout - how to change name of component

Tags: java, cardlayout

Is there any way to change the name of a panel that was added to a panel with CardLayout? I want to use the `show` method without having to use the name that I gave the panel when I added it to the main panel.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
add(panel, "0");
show(this, "0");
...              // I change name of the panel to "1"
show(this, "1"); // now I can do this to show panel
```

Comment: You want to change the variable name? You could also put the panels in a ListArray. That way you will use only one name for all the available panels. But to use this method, it would be good to have static panels that do not change much.. Then you always know that panel[0] is always panel[0]. If you will have a large set of panels, you would need a way to identify them. If you have no way to identify it is still viable if you have a limited set of panels, for example panel[0] to panel[5].

Comment: In my program, I have an ArrayList of MatrixPanels within a class called MatrixPanelContainer (which has Card Layout). As you can tell, these are custom classes. Each MatrixPanel has an ID. Let's say I have a

Comment: In my program, I have an ArrayList of MatrixPanels within a class called MatrixPanelContainer (which has Card Layout). Each MatrixPanel has an ID. I start out by adding every single MatrixPanel object from my ArrayList to my MatrixPanelContainer object by `add(matPanels.get(i), i + "")`, where `i` is iterating from 0 to matPanels.size() - 1. The problem arises when I remove a MatrixPanel from the container; I want every panel after that to have its ID decremented by 1 so that their IDs match the indices of the ArrayList. `show(this, i + "")` should show the correct panel. @CantThinkOfAnything

Comment: sorry, editing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // original cardPanel1 name is "card1"

    CardLayout lay = (CardLayout)parentPanel.getLayout();
    lay.removeLayoutComponent(cardPanel1);
    lay.addLayoutComponent(cardPanel1, "card4");

    // cardPanel1 can now be shown using "card4" name
```

Comment: This works. It is just unfortunate that I have to add and remove potentially several components whenever I remove a particular component from the main panel.

Comment: I also tried not removing the card component and it still works but the card component can be referred now with 2 names. It is also possible to assign the previous name to another component it's original card component can't be reference anymore by the  original name.